# Is it possible to make a cost analysis per project in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cost-management

I see that in `Azure Devops` the billing account is set per organization. So, I can do a cost analysis per organization. Is it possible to do the same thing on a project level with labels and etc?  I have checked but I couldn't find any labeling for the projects.
I want to see what is the exact cost of each project based on users, pipelines, parallel jobs costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find any billing per project as your question states.

As an alternative or workaround ( I'm not saying this is an ideal solution) you could separate your projects in organizations in order to be able to bill them separately.
Just in case here is the [link about billing per organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/set-up-billing-for-your-organization-vs?view=azure-devops) and here is the link for [Billing overview for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) in case it may give you some more insights.

Comment: I can confirm that this isn't available today. File a support request against Azure DevOps to let them know you can't do internal chargeback without additional details in the usage data.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do the same thing on a project level with labels and etc?

For this issue , I am afraid this is currently not possible in azure devops . Until now, billing only exists in organization level.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

In addition, for detailed information about billing, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/overview?view=azure-devops).

Comment: is it possible to set the budget scope by resource type of "azure devops" so that we can set actions accordingly?

Comment: I am not sure about this . You can [chat with sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMlKS.png) about this at the bottom of this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/).